# Condition for the rank of a matrix to be $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following matrix.

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & a & w_3 & w_4       \\
0 & 0 & x_3 & x_4       \\
0 & 0 & 1 & y_4       \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b
\end{array}\right]$

where $a, b, w_3, x_3, w_4, x_4, y_4 \in \mathbb R$ and $b \neq 0$.

I need to get a condition on $a$ for the rank of the matrix to be $2$.

Obviously $a=0$ is sufficient. I'd like to show it is necessary as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's clear that if $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$ then the last three columns are independent and the rank is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** The rank of a matrix is equal to the number of linearly independent columns. First show that the third and fourth columns are linearly independent (use the fact that $b \neq 0$). Then for the matrix to have rank two, you need the second column to be in the span of the third and fourth columns. You should be able to show that this can only happen if $a = 0$.

Comment: That's right, thanks :)